# ¿Por qué no puedo leer los datos de mi consulta, en su lugar obtengo un boolean?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

No encuentro la solución. Aquí dejo el script

```
<?php include ("conexion.php");?>
<body>

<p>hola mundo</p>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo 'Producto:'.$_GET['id'].'</br>';
    $nroreg=$_GET['id'];
    $consulta = "select * from productos where id=$nroreg";

    $resultado=mysql_query($consulta);
    $fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
    echo "productos: <br>";
    echo 'id: '.$fila['id'].'<br>';
    echo 'nombre: '.$fila['nombre'].'<br>';
}
?>

</body>
```

Comment: Hola alexander. En qué momento estás abriendo la conexión a la base de datos? Quizás ese sea el problema. Incluir un archivo php no significa que automáticamente se van a llamar a las funciones definidas en él.

Comment: Tienes que validar antes de ejecutar `mysql_fetch_array` que no haya error ya que la función `mysql_query` retorna falso cuando hay un error. Puedes usar `mysql_error` para ver el error

Comment: la conexión a BD me parece que esta dentro de: conexion.php

Comment: @César lo que indicas  en tu comentario debe ser el problema!.

Comment: mi conexion.php <?php 

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root') or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
echo 'Connected successfully';
$db = mysql_select_db('tienda') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');

?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error:

> ```
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
> ```

indica que algún parámetro es incorrecto!

Me parece que el resultado de : `mysql_query($consulta);`

```
 $resultado=mysql_query($consulta);
```

No esta obteniendo datos y marca el error cuando intentas ejecutar: `$mysql_fetch_array()`
en esta línea:

```
$fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
```

valida que `$resultado` tenga datos!

Comment: listo ya lo solucione era la variable de la columna en la base de datos no era id si no id_producto..

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué obtienes un booleano al usar `mysql_query()`?

De acuerdo a la documentación sobre [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php):

> Para SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN y otras sentencias que retornan un conjunto de resultados, mysql_query() devuelve un resource en caso de éxito, o FALSE en caso de error.

Al parecer la función `mysql_query()` está retornando algún error (considerando que la conexión a la base de datos la hagas en el archivo `conexion.php`).

Valida el resultado antes de continuar y trata de verificar el tipo de error:

```
$resultado = mysql_query($consulta);
if (!$resultado) {
    // La variable de tu conexión
    echo mysql_errno($conexion) . ": " .mysql_error($conexion) . "\n"; 
} else {
    $fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
    echo "productos: <br>";
    echo "id: " . $fila["id"] . "<br>";
    echo "nombre: " . $fila["nombre"] . "<br>";
}
```

Disculpa mi PHP-fu, hace mucho tiempo que no lo uso.